# Is it possible to dynamically assign variable names to a vector in a magrittr pipeline?

Tags: r, list, renaming, magrittr

Certain functions in `R`, such as `quantile`, lose vector names that I would like to keep. Let's say I set up the following pipeline:

```r
> dist <- c(0, 1, 2, 3)
> qnts <- c(lower = 0.25, upper = 0.75)
> qnts %>% quantile(dist, .)
#  25%. 75%
# 0.75 2.25
> qnts %>% quantile(dist, ., names = FALSE)
# [1] 0.75 2.25
```

In both cases, quantile loses the names from the `qnts` vector.

Unsurprisingly, assignment within the pipeline doesn't work:

```r
> qnts %>% quantile(dist, .) %>% names(.) <- c("upper", "lower")
# Error in qnts %>% quantile(dist, ., names = FALSE) %>% naes(.) <- c("upper",  :
#  could not find function "%>%<-"
```

I also can't use `assign`---because `names(.)` is not a variable---or rename---in this particular instance, I could use `rename(., c("25%" = "lower", "75%" = "upper"))`, but in my use case, the quantiles change dynamically.

There must be some way to intelligently recover the names of `qnts`, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try `qnts %>% quantile(dist, .) %>% 'names<-'(c("upper", "lower"))`

Comment: Or use `setNames` `qnts %>% quantile(dist, .) %>% setNames(c("upper", "lower"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `magrittr`, `set_names` would be more appropriate (which is an `Alias` for `` `names<-` ``)

```
library(magrittr)
qnts %>%
   quantile(dist, .) %>% 
   set_names(c("upper", "lower"))
#  upper lower 
# 0.75  2.25
```

Or can change the last step with `setNames` from `base R` instead of `set_names`

Another option would be to use `names<-`, but it would be less easier to understand

```
qnts %>%
   quantile(dist, .) %>%
   `names<-`(c("upper", "lower"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the assignment in braces and using a tee pipe seems to work:

```r
qnts %>% quantile(dist, .) %T>% {names(.) <- c("upper", "lower")}
```